# Failing to place an image in canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to place an image inside the canvas element.  My code is below.  When I execute it I am not getting any errors back, just a page with the outline of the border area of my canvas. Please can someone advise on where I am going wrong?

html code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title> </title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href="crop_pic.css">
 </head>

 <body>
 <div>
 <canvas id="panel" width="380" height="380"></canvas>

 </div>
 </body>

 <script src=crop_pic.js></script>  

 </html>
```

javascript:

```
window.onload = function(){
var canvas = document.getElementById('panel');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var img = new Image();
img.src = 'storage/resized_Glong.jpg';

ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

}

css:

```
 #panel{
border: 1px solid #000;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use quotes in your script tag

   ```
   <script src='crop_pic.js'></script>
   ```
2. Wait until the image is loaded and then draw it to canvas. For this add an event listener.

   ```
   window.onload = function() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById('panel');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = 'storage/resized_Glong.jpg';
   img.addEventListener('load', function() {
       ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
   });
   }
   ```

Comment: thanks man. was thinking of using a callback function to wait for the image to load but wasn't sure how to script that. Could you show me how to script a callback function for that as an alternative? is that feasible?